# How to setup a SQLAlchemy database for testing and development?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I had the following file structure in my project:

```
model/
  models.py
controller/
  controller.py
persistence/
  persistence.py
test/
  test_controller.py
```

In persistence.py I have a piece of code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db", echo=True)
BASE = declarative_base(engine)

def get_session():
     engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db", echo=False)
     Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
     session = Session()
     return session
```

Base and and engine are both used in models.py to create the database using the declarative approach.

In test_controller I import both models and persistence. When I run the tests a database is created under tests directory. The operations like update, insert, delete are performed well, but before finising the unit test SQLAlchemy raise the following exception:

```
DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Account at 0x945378c> is not bound to a Session;   
attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

All the methods that access de database closes the session, always. So, it seems that I have more than session opened.

Do you know how can I setup a sqlalchemy database for testing and other for developing just like Rails does using the same model module? Any idea?

here the test code:

```
from model import Account

engine = create_engine("sqlite://database-test.db", echo=True)
BASE = declarative_base(engine)
BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

def delete_account(account):
  if account:
    session.delete(account)
    session.commit()
    session.flush()
    session.close()

class TestBankController(unittest.TestCase):


  def test_insert_bank_twice(self):
    controller = Account()
    bank = Account('TestAcct')
    controller.create_account(bank)
    try:
        print "tentando inserir repetido"
        bank2 = BankAccount("TestAcct")
        controller.create_account(bank2)
        assert False == True
    except ApplicationException:
        print "ok"


if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

and, in the model.py I have the following:

```
 engine = create_engine("sqlite:///database.db", echo=True)
 BASE = declarative_base(engine)

 class Account(BASE):
   __tablename__ = "accounts_tb"
   id = Column(Integer, Sequence('account_iq_seq'), primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String(250))
   agency = Column(String(40))
   number = Column(String(40))
   initial_balance = Column(Integer)

BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your answer and include the test code?

Comment: Hi Mark, I updated the question and I put the test code and the model code.

Comment: There is really a lot of code here that seems out of place. You have flushes occurring after commits (commits will implicitly do a flush), engines and metadata being created in three different places... and we still don't know what the controller looks like. I would recommend you take a few steps back, as it seems that you're not really sure what all of the parts of SQLAlchemy are actually doing. Be sure to read through the SQLAlchemy tutorial and understand what the engine, metadata, and session actually are doing in simple scripts.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm reading the SQAlchemy documentation and about OO in python. I'm not python programmer, I'm still learning the concepts which is very different from someone that come from java. But, nothing more than a practical problem to solve...